# What is the symbolism of the two pools of water in this picture

Tags: shiva

[image: Shiva symbolism]

On each side of this picture there is a pool of water. It looks to be flowing in from the right ear and flowing out of the left. What is this about?

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE:
The previous question deals with the water coming from the crown of the head. I'm talking about the pools of water water at the ears.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE: The previous question deals with the water coming from the crown of the head. I'm talking about the pools of water water at the ears.

Comment: They are not water pools coming from ears. They are **Shiva's hair**. Actually it is a tricky picture. You can see many in one pic.

Comment: What is seen in ear area is the Vedi (base) of Shiva Linga seen in top of head... and in background it forms like ear...

Comment: This picture is not accurate. It's Yoni of Shiva Linga. See [this picture](https://shrikashivishwanath.org/css/images/shivlingameaning.gif).